# LIMIT Alternatives

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this query and $from has a really big value, it takes too much in returning the answer (more than 30 secs).

Is there any way to go directly to the $from row and return $users_per_page amount of records without go through the whole database?

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_id LIMIT ' . $from. ' , '. $users_per_page;
```

Comment: Is there an index on `user_id`?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an index on user_id will prevent a table scan. As long as users_per_page is small then the query will be fast.

```
CREATE INDEX index_users_on_user_id ON users (user_id);
```

Comment: Thanks!. I am trying to create the INDEX through phpMyAdmin and it gives me an error: Gateway Time-out

The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application

Comment: My guess is that you need to do this with the proper [MySQL client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html). I'm assuming, from your question, that this table is big and adding this index will take time. PHP scripts and phpMyAdmin are likely to time out while waiting for MySQL to respond saying all has been done.

Comment: Once I create the INDEX, will the query be the same?